# Using python 2.7. logging in python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-2.6

Is there a way to use the logging package of python 2.7 in python 2.6?

There are a few things that I need like not [disabling existing loggers or the dictConfig function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#module-logging.config).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`logutils`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/logutils) package might serve your needs - it backports certain functions - including `dictConfig()` - to earlier Python versions.